# hide/show button for checking result in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to run the following code which I thought stright forward but I keep getting **; layer = >**

The storyboard has 3 textfields and two buttons and the message I got is when the answer is right (second part of If statement.
Thanks,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Create outlet for both the button
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!



@IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var result: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt2: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //hidden button on start
   button2.isHidden = true

}



//Here is the actionbutton1 which is visible
@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Make button2 Visible
    let firstValue : Int? = Int(txt1.text!)
    let secondValue : Int? = Int(txt2.text!)

    let convert = firstValue! + secondValue!
   let converText = String(convert)


    //result.text = converText
    if result.text != converText {
    print ("wrong")
    button2.isHidden = true

    }
        else{
        print(result)// result right

    //show the button
  button2.isHidden = false


    }

}

}
```

Comment: What actually the requirement is ?

Comment: why getting <UITextField: 0x7fb90f827c00; frame = (104 183; 136 30); text = '7'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000246fc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x604000228c20>>

Comment: @Farisk: because of you print the `result UITextField` object, not text

Comment: In the else part change code `print(result)` to this `print(result.text!)`, because of trying to print textfield object you are getting the above text in console.

Comment: All that I'm doing is adding two numbers and the result is in the result field. If the result of adding is right, the other button will show up else print me a "wrong" in council. Everything is working but when the answer is right I got that message and do I ignore it? Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the print (result) which I used it for testing and it works!

Comment: One more thing I'm getting Hide debug Gauges which show me the activity of the memory, CPU, and disk, is that normal? Thanks